# smartgwt - two neighbour panels (vlayouts) is not resizable

Tags: java, eclipse, web, resize, smartgwt

I've got a gwt project which contains two Vlayouts(dialogVLeftPanel, dialogVRightPanel). That Vlayouts contain a treegrid, like at code below:

```
/////////// drzewo użytkowników
        userViewTree = new Tree();  
        userViewTree.setModelType(TreeModelType.PARENT);  
        userViewTree.setIdField("UserViewId");  
        userViewTree.setParentIdField("ReportsTo");  
        userViewTree.setNameProperty("Użytkownicy");  
        userViewTree.setRootValue(1);  
        userViewTree.setData(userViewData);  

        TreeGrid userViewTreeGrid = new TreeGrid();  
        userViewTreeGrid.setHeight(600);
        userViewTreeGrid.setWidth(185); 
        userViewTreeGrid.setShowOpenIcons(false);  
        userViewTreeGrid.setShowDropIcons(false);  
        userViewTreeGrid.setClosedIconSuffix("");  
        userViewTreeGrid.setFields(new TreeGridField("Użytkownicy"));  
        userViewTreeGrid.setData(userViewTree);
        userViewTreeGrid.getData().openAll();  
        dialogVLeftPanel.addMember(userViewTreeGrid);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////drzewo uprawnień/////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Tree userTree = new Tree();  
        userTree.setModelType(TreeModelType.PARENT);  
        userTree.setRootValue(1);  
        userTree.setNameProperty("Uprawnienia");  
        userTree.setIdField("userId");  
        userTree.setParentIdField("ReportsTo");  
        userTree.setOpenProperty("isOpen");  
        userTree.setData(userData);  


        final TreeGrid userTreeGrid = new TreeGrid();  
        userTreeGrid.setHeight(600);  
        userTreeGrid.setWidth(630);
        userTreeGrid.setShowOpenIcons(false);  
        userTreeGrid.setShowDropIcons(false);  
        userTreeGrid.setClosedIconSuffix("");  
        userTreeGrid.setData(userTree);  
        userTreeGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);  
        userTreeGrid.setFields(new TreeGridField("Uprawnienia"));  
        userTreeGrid.setShowSelectedStyle(false);  
        userTreeGrid.setShowPartialSelection(true);  
        userTreeGrid.setCascadeSelection(true);          
        dialogVRightPanel.addMember(userTreeGrid);
```

I wanna put the resisable bar between that Vlayouts, because I wanna change both width when I wish to do it.
When I put that code:

userTreeGrid.setShowResizeBar(true);
The resize bar is visible, but it is on the bottom of Vlayout and can only shorten the panel. If I wanna make wider the panel - it is not working. 
How could I solve my problem?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set two `VLayout` so you need to apply `setShowResizeBar(true)` on you left `VLayout` not to your `TreeGrid` because what you really want is to be able to resize the containers.